# mysql import sql via cli from remote server

Tags: mysql, import, command-line-interface

i know how to import an sql file via the cli:

```
mysql -u USER -p DBNAME < dump.sql
```

but that's if the dump.sql file is local. how could i use a file on a remote server?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You didn't say what network access you have to the remote server.

Assuming you have SSH access to the remote server, you could pipe the results of a remote mysqldump to the mysql command. I just tested this, and it works fine:

```
ssh remote.com "mysqldump remotedb" | mysql localdb
```

I put stuff like user, password, host into `.my.cnf` so I'm not constantly typing them -- annoying and bad for security on multiuser systems, you are putting passwords in cleartext into your bash_history! But you can easily add the `-u -p -h` stuff back in on both ends if you need it:

```
ssh remote.com "mysqldump -u remoteuser -p'remotepass' remotedb" | mysql -u localuser -p'localpass' localdb
```

Finally, you can pipe through `gzip` to compress the data over the network:

```
ssh remote.com "mysqldump remotedb | gzip" | gzip -d | mysql localdb
```

Comment: This helped me a lot when I was migrating servers. Hope the asker can select this as the answer to the question.

Comment: What if I don't have ssh access but I can connect to the distant mysql server via my local "mysql --host=mydomain.com --user=user --pass=pass ? How do I retrieve the *.sql file I need to dump ?

Comment: Is there a limit to database dump sizes when using the first method (pipe)?

Answer (score 3):

Just thought I'd add to this as I was seriously low on space on my local VM, but if the .sql file exists already on the remote server you could do;

```
ssh <ip-address> "cat /path/to/db.sql" | mysql -u <user> -p<password> <dbname>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) to either download it to a file or pipe it in.